# Newton (Iterative) Vs. Babylonian (Direct) For Roots

Tags: numerical-methods

Is Newton's iterative method for finding a square root more efficient then the Babylonian method? Considering most roots are irrational, which method would get me within, say 16 decimal places, the fastest? I need a high level of precision so I was curious which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Newton-Raphson process for the case of the square root is in effect the same algorithm as the Babylonian Method, aka Heron's Method.

Answer (score 3):

There are many clever tricks for computing square roots quickly. This is especially true if you really want the reciprocal of a square root, or if you want a square root of the form $\sqrt{ a^2 + b^2}$. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root), for starters.

Answer (score 2):

If speed and robustness is key, check [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Brent.27s_Method)